# Пытаюсь исключить дефолтный логгер из spring-boot-starter но <exclusion> не срабатывает (LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, логирование, log4j

Пытаюсь исключить дефолтный логгер из spring-boot-starter, чтобы вместо него использовать сконфигурированный Log4j, но exclusion которое я добавил в зависимость в pom.xml не помогает и я ловлю эту ошибку:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the
> classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation
> (class org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from
> file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.10.0/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar).
> If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to
> prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml:
> org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory

В чем проблема? Как ее решить?

Вот мой pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>app</name>
    <description>app</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <xchange.version>4.3.9</xchange.version>
        <xchange-stream.version>4.3.3-SNAPSHOT</xchange-stream.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Вот мой log4j2-spring.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%style{%d{ISO8601}}{black} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{bright,blue}] %style{%C{1.}}{bright,yellow}: %msg%n%throwable"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                     fileName="./logs/app-log4j2.log"
                     filePattern="./logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-log4j2-%d{-dd-MMMM-yyyy}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <!-- rollover on startup, daily and when the file reaches
                    10 MegaBytes -->
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
                        size="10 MB"/>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Root>

        <!-- LOG "com.app*" at TRACE level -->
        <Logger name="com.app" level="trace"></Logger>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Comment: Кто-то продолжает его подтаскивать. Проверь с помошью `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: @Alexander выполнил mvn dependency:tree , Build succese. ищу упоминания про spring-boot-starter-logging и не нахожу. Или я должен искать что-то другое?

Comment: Logback надо искать